# Ответ серверу Telegram

Tags: python-3.x, telegram-bot, flask, telegram

Есть сервер на Flask который принимает обновления от telegram по средствам webhook

```
@app.route('/', methods = ['POST', 'GET'])
    def index():
        if request.method == 'POST':
            r = request.get_json()
            foo(r)
            return'OK'
        return 'OK'
```

Мы получаем обновление от telegram в виде json и что-то с ним делаем в foo(). Потом отправляем в telegram что угодно, главное чтобы ответ был с кодом 200 (обновление получено, всё в порядке).

Проблема заключается в следующем: timeout телеграмма может сработать раньше чем функция foo() выполнит свою работу, и тогда telegram пришлет обновление ещё раз (посчитав что мы его не получили), ситуация повторится, в общем образовывается петля. Функция foo() будет обрабатывать одно и тоже обновление.

Вопрос - как сделать так чтобы сервер при получении обновления сразу же отвечал OK 200 после чего foo() начинала свою работу?

Буду очень признателен за любую помощь в решении данной проблемы!

Ниже полный листинг бота:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask import request
from flask import jsonify
import telebot
import fssp

TOKEN = '<MY TOKEN>'
chat_id = '<chat id>'
WEBHOOK_HOST = '111.111.111.111'
WEBHOOK_PORT = '443'
WEBHOOK_SSL_CERT = './certificates/webhook_cert.pem'
WEBHOOK_SSL_PRIV = './certificates/webhook_pkey.pem'
WEBHOOK_URL_BASE = "https://%s:%s" % (WEBHOOK_HOST, WEBHOOK_PORT)
bot = telebot.TeleBot(TOKEN)
app = Flask(__name__)
bot.remove_webhook()
fssp.sleep(1)
bot.set_webhook(url=WEBHOOK_URL_BASE, certificate=open(WEBHOOK_SSL_CERT, 
'r'))

@app.route('/', methods = ['POST', 'GET'])
def index():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        r = request.get_json()
        result_fssp_answer = fssp.search(r['message']['text'])
        if type(result_fssp_answer) is str:
            bot.send_message(chat_id, result_fssp_answer)
            return jsonify(r)
        file_name = r['message']['text'].split()
        file_name.pop()
        file_name = ' '.join(file_name) + '.txt'
        file_name = file_name.lower().replace('ё', 'е').strip()
        with open('./reports/' + file_name, 'rb') as ouf:
            bot.send_document(chat_id, ouf)
        return jsonify(r)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='111.111.111.111', port=443, ssl_context= 
    (WEBHOOK_SSL_CERT, WEBHOOK_SSL_PRIV))
```

Comment: Прикрепите листинг с кодом запроса из телеграм бота

Comment: Прикрепил листинг бота

Comment: Решил данную проблему многопоточностью (библиотека threading.Thread) функция foo() запускается отдельным потоком, т.е. выполнение кода не останавливается, а идёт далее т.е. отправляет ОК 200 серверу телеграмма